# Strange date format

Tags: date, formatting

I am working with a partner who is producing a delimited file for me. The dates are formatted as:

> 2013.07.06 AD at 01:00:00 GMT

The other company doesn't really have an IT department, so they can't tell me where the format came from. Assuming it is a standard date format, does anyone know which library or database engine would produce this format without a custom format string?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

The partner in question was able to get an answer. For reasons that make no sense to me, the underlying software, written in Java, explicitly formats the date this way, with the `" at "` and era and time zone indicators. A rather strange choice for a file that is supposed to be consumed by a computer program with no human interaction - they produce a beautiful, human-reasonable Excel file from the same data.

Anyways, thanks for looking and commenting.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned the only standard date / time format is ISO8601 (ext). The format you have is not a million miles from that. I suggest you test your format with a regex, and tweak it to ISO8601. Then proceed from there. Which language are you using by the way?

Comment: It's a variant of ISO8601 format, using a `.` instead of the more standard `-`, which is something you tend to see in European countries (mainland Europe, not odd-ball islands offshore like the UK).  The AD is unusual and largely superfluous (dates BC or BCE are seldom encountered electronically); the 'at' is unusual and just noise; and GMT would probably be better as UTC, but what the heck.  ISO8601 gives guidelines on formats but allows parties to agree to alternative formats.